# Change a character date to numeric date and then extract year in a data frame

Tags: r, character, as.date

I have a large data frame (d) with the dates as character class. I want to extract the year only but first, I have been trying to convert to as date first and then extract the year. However I cannot change date from character.
So I have two questions - how do I change this character date to a numeric date and then how do I extract the year?
I am looking for the easiest way so I can recreate with other data sets.

```
site<dbl> date<chr> conc<dbl>
2001    2/1/1980    0.006521739     
2001    2/2/1980    0.008260870     
2001    2/3/1980    0.005652174     
2001    2/4/1980    0.007826087     
2001    2/5/1980    0.001000000     
2001    2/7/1980    0.002222222     
2001    2/8/1980    0.008666667     
2001    2/11/1980   0.017777778     
2001    2/12/1980   0.016250000     
2001    2/13/1980   0.015416667
```

Here is what I have tried:
`d2 <- as.Date(d$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y)`

I get this error message:

> Error: Incomplete expression: d2 <- as.Date(d$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y)

Comment: You forgot one `"` at the end

Comment: Awesome! I did this and it worked: d2 <- d %>% mutate(date = as.Date(d$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))

Comment: BUT second part of question is how do I extract the year only?

Comment: see answer below

Comment: Yes two great solutions! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
d <- read.table(text="
site     date       conc
2001    2/1/1980    0.006521739     
2001    2/2/1980    0.008260870     
2001    2/3/1980    0.005652174     
2001    2/4/1980    0.007826087     
2001    2/5/1980    0.001000000     
2001    2/7/1980    0.002222222     
2001    2/8/1980    0.008666667     
2001    2/11/1980   0.017777778     
2001    2/12/1980   0.016250000     
2001    2/13/1980   0.015416667 ",header=T)


d %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date,'%m/%d/%Y'),
             year = year(as.Date(date,'%m/%d/%Y')))

   site       date        conc year
1  2001 1980-02-01 0.006521739  1980
2  2001 1980-02-02 0.008260870  1980
3  2001 1980-02-03 0.005652174  1980
4  2001 1980-02-04 0.007826087  1980
5  2001 1980-02-05 0.001000000  1980
6  2001 1980-02-07 0.002222222  1980
7  2001 1980-02-08 0.008666667  1980
8  2001 1980-02-11 0.017777778  1980
9  2001 1980-02-12 0.016250000  1980
10 2001 1980-02-13 0.015416667  1980
```